# translate SQL query to linq query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the following query and I want to write this in Linq(using c#). How should I do it?

```
declare @parentId bigint
set @parentId = (select ArticlePart from tbl_Article where ArticleID = 70001)
declare @ids varchar(100)
set @ids=''
while @parentId is not null
begin
    set @ids = @ids +CAST( @parentId as varchar(50))+','
    set @parentId = (select ArticlePart from tbl_Article where ArticleID = @parentId)
end
```

Comment: For best performance you should write this as a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) in SQL. Not linq.

Comment: Linq cannot do control flow, nor can it do recursive CTEs. I would suggest that you write a recursive CTE as Magnus suggests, and then use either EF or L2S or nHibernate to do the mapping of the query results into objects.

Comment: check out Linqer http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: In case the suggestions from **Magnus** and **Aron** aren't feasible, what exactly is your difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

Not that it might be the best solution to the problem, but answering the question:

```
var ids = string.Join(",", ArticleQueriable(articles, 70001));


Queriable<int> ArticleQueriable(Queriable<Article> tbl_Article, int parentID)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var parent = tbl_Article.SingleOrDefault(a => a.ArticleID == parentID);

        if (parent != null)
        {
            parentID = parent.ArticlePart.Dump();
            yield return parentID;
        }
        else
        {
            yield break;
        }
    }
}
```